# Why does Windows 7 confuse the shortcut with the exe-file?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

Somewhat related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/515127/how-to-remove-program-shortcuts-on-the-desktop-in-window-in-windows-7), which I found when googling why I get this dialogue when attempting to delete a shortcut from my desktop:

[image]

As you can see from the highlighted texts, there is a discrepancy between the file I have selected and the file Windows actually asks me if I want to delete. From some googling, I've discovered that [the only thing which actually (most likely) will be deleted](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/172907-how-delete-shortcuts-desktop-post1474829.html#post1474829) if I answer "Continue" to that dialogue is the shortcut, but I still find it odd that the question pops up. Can anyone here shed any light on why this happens?

The answers to the above-mentioned question seems to indicate that desktop-shortcuts which are shared among all users (this one is) require admin-privileges to delete, but then I would expect the confirmation-dialogue to say this is why I need to grant admin-access, not that it is because I try to delete an exe-file. Which it doesn't say, strictly speaking, but the path it indicates surely isn't to the desktop.

Comment: Open the shortcut's properties, and look at its physical path. it is likely actually inside the c:\users\default\Desktop\ directory. the Default user is a template for all user accounts, so stuff in default appears to be in your profile, but is not. There have been a number of exploits over the years that involved using shortcuts to trick users into opening bad exe's, so modifications to the default users desktop shortcuts or startmenu shortcuts requires administrator priviledges because it affects other users of the system. The dialog is just extended to show the target of the link.

Comment: Well, yeah, but why does pressing delete when selecting that file say that it attempts to delete what is in that folder described in the dialogue, and not the file on the desktop (or in the shared users folder)? @FrankThomas

Comment: it isn't, but they could have formatted the dialog better. It is telling you it will delete the file 'Acrobat Reader DC' (they really need to show extensions by default; that was a bad idea, and would have made this more clear).  The dialog has been extended for .lnk files to show the target of the link, but thats just property infomation. the dialog is not trying to tell you it wants to delete Acrord32, just that the lnk being deleted points to it. This info would be useful if you did not recognize the lnk name or icon.

Comment: Oh, right - yeah, that explains it. Reading comprehension fail for me, I guess, and pretty bad design by Microsoft :) @FrankThomas

Comment: its also possible that MS made this dialog diliberately scary to help crapware/bundleware OEMs and vendors happy, by keeping pointless icons in view of clueless users. MS deals directly with OEMs, and that relationship is essential to how they rose to power and remained there.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be the first time they have used fear as part of a system design. in the old days, if you opened Regedit for the first time, a popup would appear to tell you that you would void your warrentee by making ANY change to the registery. Since every program installation writes somthing to the registery, that implies that the windows warrentee is void as soon as you install the first 3rd party program.  There was outcry, and possibly court cases (I don't remember the mid-90 's as well as I should I suppose) and it eventually went away, by shifting support to OEMs.

Answer (score 0):

This dialog attempts to provide useful context information. The exact same content is also presented in an item’s tooltip. This behavior is not specific to the “elevation required”-type dialog.

Other than that, it’s pretty much opinion-based. Unless the actual developer/designer answers.

Comment: Yeah, but the file I try to delete is on the desktop (or maybe in the shared user's folder), so why does the dialogue point to destination folder for the shortcut? I read that dialogue as me needing admin-privileges because I try to delete a file in a folder I normally don't have write-access to (the one described in the dialogue).

Comment: Like I said, it’s the default file metadata tooltip content. The “Location” field only appears for shortcuts. That’s because it’s good to know where a shortcut’s actual target is. If you were to enter a “Comment”, it would appear in place of the “Location” field.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine that is because you are either deleting the file from:

- Default Users' Desktop: %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Users\Default\Desktop\
- OR Public Users' Desktop: %PUBLIC%\Desktop\

You can confirm by right-clicking the shortcut, Properties, General tab, & seeing the Location. It prompts you because it will **affect ALL users** on the PC & is usually unwanted behavior